# Spring MVC: <cache:annotation-driven> generate Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource

Tags: java, xml, spring-mvc, caching, model-view-controller

I'm trying to configure cache in spring MVC 3.2

Since I never used it I'm just following some handy guide. My problem is:  generate an `Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aopalliance/intercept/MethodInterceptor`

I checked build-path in eclipse, everything is ok. Below my spring-servlet.xml config file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd">


    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <cache:annotation-driven/>
```

It doesn't matter what I add after `<cache:annotation-driven/>`, it will end in error. Everything works the right way only if I remove the annotation cache.

Since this is well explained in spring doc, where I'm getting wrong in this code? I need some kind of external library?

Comment: You seem to be missing aopappliance.jar in your runtime path.

Comment: Is this something like http://stackoverflow.com/q/22282107/2040545 ?

Comment: I followed your link before my post and, sadly, it doesn't work for me.

Comment: UPDATE: I don't know why, but moving `<cache:annotation-driven/>` just below  `<context:component-scan base-package="com.my.package" />` it works! I don't know why, but it works ONLY IF I put it just after component-scan (not in the end or middle of spring servlet). Never thought that there was a priority order like this (except for annotation driven).
So, for me is solved but I don't think it's a "standard" solution.